# 配列内に存在する同じプレフィックスのキーで値がある場合のみ、別途格納したい

Tags: php

```
$dataAry
(
    [a] => 
    [b] => 
    [d_1] => 
    [hoge_1] => 
    [c_1] =>
    [d_2] => 
    [hoge_2] => https://xxxx
    [c_2] =>
    [d_3] => 
    [hoge_3] => 
    [c_3] => 
)
```

**上記配列に対して実行したい処理**
・hoge_xに値がある時、hoge_xの値を$hogeAryへ格納
・hoge_xに値がある時、d_xの値を$dAryへ格納
→ hoge_2に値があるので、hoge_2の値を$hogeAryへ格納
→ hoge_2に値があるので、d_2の値を$dAryへ格納
※hoge_xの値が複数ある場合は、サフィックス昇順で格納
※上記以外のキーは関係ありません

欲しい結果

```
$hogeAry
(
    [0] => https://xxxx
)
$dAry
(
    [0] => 
)
```

---

作成したいコードのイメージ

```
$dAry=array();
$hogeAry=array();
foreach ($dataAry as $key=>$val){
  if(hoge_xに値がある時){
    $hogeAry[]=$val;
  }
  if(hoge_xに値がある時){
    x(であるサフィックス数値)を取得;
  }
}
foreach ($dataAry as $key=>$val){
  if($key==data_x){ //上記のようにhoge_xに値があるケースが1件だけならこれで良いと思うが、複数あった場合の書き方は？
    $dataAry[]=$val;
  }
}
```

Comment: 対象のデータが単純な配列ではなく「連想配列」を想定しているように見えます。

Comment: @cubick さん、PHPはすべての配列が連想配列ですから、「連想配列」のことを「配列」と書くのは普通のことです。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$dAry=array();
$hogeAry=array();
foreach ($dataAry as $key=>$val){
  if(strpos($key,'hoge_') !== false){
    $dAry[]=str_replace('hoge_', '', $key);
    $hogeAry[]=$val;
  }
}
array_multisort($dAry, SORT_ASC, $hogeAry);
```

こんな感じですかね。デバッグしてないですが。